# Combining text wrapping and shrinking in WPF

Tags: wpf, textview, word-wrap, text-size

I my WPF app I have a relatively small box of limited width, where I need to display some text which has been entered by the user. The text can realistically be expected to be between one and five words, but the words can easily be larger than the box.

If the text is too long, but contains multiple words which can be broken up into lines, I'd want the text to wrap. However, if any single word is too large to fit, then I want the text size to shrink until that word is small enough to fit, regardless of whether or not that text is also wrapping. I don't care how much vertical space the text takes up.

Here's an example I put together manually in Excel to demonstrate the intended behavior:
[image: Example]

In example 1 the whole text fits in the box.
In example 2 the text is two words, so it can be wrapped without shrinking the text.
In example 3, the single word is too long so the text has to be shrunk.
In example 4 the text can be wrapped but it still contains a word that is too long to fit, so the text has to be shrunk until that longest word can fit.

How can I accomplish this in WPF? I haven't been able to find a combination of `ViewBox` and `TextBlock.TextWrapping` which does this.

**EDIT:**
If I *do* have to do this manually (which would be a bit of a nightmare), then is there at least a way I can figure out what the TextBlock decides is a "line"? I would need to know how it's going to break up the text before I could identify if any one "line" is going to be too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as no real solution to this exists, I ended up coding it myself:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Controls
Imports System.Windows.Documents

    Public Class TextScalerBehavior
        Public Shared ReadOnly ShrinkToFitProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ShrinkToFit", GetType(Boolean), GetType(TextScalerBehavior), New PropertyMetadata(False, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf ShrinkToFitChanged)))

        Public Shared Function GetShrinkToFit(obj As TextBlock) As Boolean
            Return obj.GetValue(ShrinkToFitProperty)
        End Function

        Public Shared Sub SetShrinkToFit(obj As TextBlock, value As Boolean)
            obj.SetValue(ShrinkToFitProperty, value)
        End Sub

        Protected Shared Sub ShrinkToFitChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
            Dim tb As TextBlock = d

            If e.NewValue Then
                tb.AddHandler(TextBlock.SizeChangedEvent, TargetSizeChangedEventHandler)
                With DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextBlock.TextProperty, GetType(TextBlock))
                    .AddValueChanged(tb, TargetTextChangedEventHandler)
                End With
                tb.AddHandler(TextBlock.LoadedEvent, TargetLoadedEventHandler)
            Else
                tb.RemoveHandler(TextBlock.SizeChangedEvent, TargetSizeChangedEventHandler)
                With DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextBlock.TextProperty, GetType(TextBlock))
                    .RemoveValueChanged(tb, TargetTextChangedEventHandler)
                End With
                tb.RemoveHandler(TextBlock.LoadedEvent, TargetLoadedEventHandler)
            End If
        End Sub

        Protected Shared ReadOnly TargetSizeChangedEventHandler As New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf TargetSizeChanged)

        Protected Shared Sub TargetSizeChanged(Target As TextBlock, e As RoutedEventArgs)
            Update(Target)
        End Sub

        Protected Shared ReadOnly TargetTextChangedEventHandler As New EventHandler(AddressOf TargetTextChanged)

        Protected Shared Sub TargetTextChanged(Target As TextBlock, e As EventArgs)
            Update(Target)
        End Sub

        Protected Shared ReadOnly TargetLoadedEventHandler As New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf TargetLoaded)

        Protected Shared Sub TargetLoaded(Target As TextBlock, e As RoutedEventArgs)
            Update(Target)
        End Sub

        Private Shared ReadOnly Shrinkging As New HashSet(Of TextBlock)

        Protected Shared Sub Update(Target As TextBlock)
            If Target.IsLoaded Then
                Dim Clip = Primitives.LayoutInformation.GetLayoutClip(Target)

                If Clip IsNot Nothing Then
                    If Not Shrinkging.Contains(Target) Then Shrinkging.Add(Target)
                    Target.FontSize -= 1
                ElseIf Target.FontSize < TextElement.GetFontSize(Target.Parent) Then
                    If Shrinkging.Contains(Target) Then
                        Shrinkging.Remove(Target)
                    Else
                        Target.FontSize += 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
```

This class implements the behavior I need as a WPF attached behavior using attached dependency properties. The magic happens in the final routine: `Update`.

In WPF, if a given element is being clipped (i.e. it's bigger than the space it's allowed to take up, so it gets cut off), then `LayoutInformation.GetLayoutClip` returns data on what area of the element is visible. If an element is not clipped, this seems to return null (though the docs don't say that).
A TextBlock with `TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"` will "overflow" past the edges of its container if any single line is too big to be broken correctly.
The `Update` routine checks to see if this clipping is occurring and if so lowers the font size by 1. This changes the size of the TextBlock and triggers another round of `Update`, which continues the cycle until the element no longer clips.
There is also additional logic to scale the font back up to its original size if the available space increases.

An example of usage is:

```
<TextBlock [YourNamespace]:TextScalerBehavior.ShrinkToFit="True" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
```

Remember that `TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"` is required.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this manually. The following code sample adjusts the font size of a `TextBox` until all text fits in to the viewport (maximum available space for text rendering). You have to execute this method from an event handler that is registered to the `TextBoxBase.TextChanged` event:

```
protected void ResizeTextToFit(TextBox textBox)
{
  // Make sure the first line is always visible
  textBox.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);

  bool fontSizeHasChanged = false;

  // Shrink to fit as long
  // the last visible line is not the last line or
  // the true text height is bigger than the visible text height
  // and prevent font size to be set to '0'
  while (textBox.FontSize > 1 
         && (textBox.GetLastVisibleLineIndex() < textBox.LineCount - 1 
             || textBox.ExtentHeight > textBox.ViewportHeight))
  {
    fontSizeHasChanged = true;
    textBox.FontSize -= 1.0;
  }

  if (fontSizeHasChanged)
  {
    return;
  }

  // Enlarge to fit as long the last line is visible 
  // and the text height fits into the viewport
  while (textBox.GetLastVisibleLineIndex() == textBox.LineCount - 1 
         && textBox.ExtentHeight < textBox.ViewportHeight)
  {
    textBox.FontSize += 1.0;
  }
  textBox.FontSize -= 1.0;
}
```

You may prefer to extend your own class from `TextBox` to encapsulate this behavior.

This example depends on a `TextBox` that has a fixed `Width` and `Height`, so that it cann't resize to the content.